# Zabbix Log Monitoring - Duplicate alerts ..Received multiple alerts

Tags: logging, monitoring, zabbix

I have configured Zabbix to monitor my java application log for string "None of the configured nodes are available".

Everything is working fine, Zabbix will send me alerts when there is a new String "None of the configured nodes are available" entry in the log file, But issue is for each entry of string zabbix trigger alert and I received mail with different-2 event id.

My configuration of the log monitoring is below.
I am using the latest version of zabbix server(3.4)

**Item configuration:**

Description: log monitoring.
Key: log[/home/ubuntu/logs/dev.log,None of the configured nodes are available]
Type: Zabbix Agent (Active)
Type of information: Log
Interval :30

**Trigger configuration:**

Description: Log-None of the configured nodes are available {HOST.NAME}.
Expression: {Dev:log[/home/ubuntu/logs/dev.log,None of the configured nodes are available].str(NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available)}=1
PROBLEM event generation mode:Multiple